# How to return correct type from a function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface Functor<T> {
  map <T1>(f: (x: T) => T1): Functor<T1>
}


interface Maybe<T> extends Functor<T> {}
```

Next, I have `map` function implementation, which takes `Functor` and calls it `.map` method:

```
function map<T, U>(f: (x: T) => U, a: Functor<T>): Functor<U>

function map(f, a) {
  return a.map(f);
}
```

If I use this `map` function with `Maybe`, return type of it will be `Functor<T>` instead of `Maybe<T>`:

```
// type is Maybe<number>
const mb = new Just(5);

// type is Functor<string>, but should be Maybe<string>
const result = map((x) => 'str', mb)
```

I can solve this by adding additional overload to `map` function:

```
function map<T, U>(f: (x: T) => U, a: Maybe<T>): Maybe<U>
```

But the problem is that `Functor` and `Maybe` types are in different npm packages and `map` function implementation doesn't know anything about `Maybe`.

How, can I achieve this?

Comment: As far as I know that isn't possible. Even with Generic constraints you would be stuck with `function map<T, U, FT extends Functor<T>, FU extends Functor<U>>(f: (x: T) => U, a: FT): FU;`, which isn't really more useful than the definition you are using.

Comment: @Stephan correct, with that definition, function return type is still `Functor<T>` unfortunately

Comment: I think the only thing you could do is to file a feature request at TypeScript's GitHub repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript currently (as of 2.4) lacks [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), which is what you need to properly express the relationship between the `a` parameter and the return value.  If, for example, TypeScript allowed a generic type parameter to itself be generic, you could say this:

```
function map<T, U, F<X> extends Functor<X>>(f: (x: T) => U, a: F<T>): F<U> {...}
```

(using an `F<X>` notation I just made up), or:

```
function map<T, U, F extends Functor>(f: (x: T) => U, a: F<T>): F<U> {...}
```

(using the bare `Functor` in a way you can't do currently).

Then the compiler would presumably automatically infer `Maybe` for `F`.

If you think your use case is compelling enough, you might want to go to [the relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) and show your support for it by contributing or at least giving a  to the top post.

---

As @Stephan pointed out, there aren't really any workarounds much better than what you're currently doing.  I've occasionally tried my hand at implementing functors and the like in not-expressive-enough languages and it ends up devolving into a sea of manual type annotations and unchecked type assertions.  I mostly recommend giving up ☹️ and implementing only the *specific* functors you need without trying to abstract over them.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.